# Is there a visual (e.g. nuget style in Visual Studio) package manager?

Tags: react-native, npm, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg, package-managers

I've started my first react native project and things are finally starting to go quite smoothly, but I really can't say I care for the way 3rd party dependencies are installed with npm/yarn.

As a Microsoft developer I'm looking at this wondering if these tools were developed by neanderthals? Okay, okay, I get it a lot of you think it's cool and it's a culture/tradition thing that once you get used to it it's not a big deal and maybe you feel it's even "better".

But I'm also reminded of a boss who once said "people don't want pictures... they want information!" in response to Window's/Apple's early operating systems. Boy did he miss it.

I want the pictures. Where is my visual package manager? Is there one?

And for reference, I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-gui?activeTab=readme

Comment: @Maxqueue Awesome, checking it out now. Btw, that's actually an answer... not just a comment, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:
https://npmjs.com/package/npm-gui?activeTab=readme

Ironically need to install using npm command line